# More functional os.walk

Tags: python

Since I need to do many traversals of directories, which some complex filtering, I thought to create a wrapper around os.walk.

Which is something like this:

```
def fwalk(root, pred_dir, pred_files, walk_function=walk):
    """Wrapper function around the standard os.walk, that filter out
    the directories visited using a filtering predicate
    """

    for base, dirs, files in walk_function(root):
        # ignore also the root directory when not needed, which is
        # actually more important than the subdirectories
        dirs = [d for d in dirs if pred_dir(path.join(base, d))]
        files = [f for f in files if pred_files(path.join(base, f))]

        if _ignore_dirs_predicate(base) and (dirs or files):
            yield base, dirs, files
```

Basically it behaves as os.walk, but takes two predicates to make it a bit nicer to compose in higher-level functions.
For example this will only go through the python modules:

```
ISA_PY = lambda f: f[-3:] == '.py'
# I can make it a class or maybe even a module if it's better
def walk_py(src):
    # should not be in the list
    return fwalk(src, _ignore_dirs_predicate, ISA_PY)
```

It also takes a walk function which for example can be just a dummy walk, used for testing.

```
def dummy_walk(_):
    test_dir = [
        ('/root/', ['d1, .git'], []),
        ('/root/d1', [], ['setup.py']),
        ('/root/test', [], ['test1.py']),
        ('/root/.git', [], [])
    ]

    # returns a function which  skips the parameter and return the iterator
    return iter(test_dir)
```

The problem now is that I find it very hard to trust this function, apart from the some unit testing using the dummy walk is quite hard to make sure it's correct.

Any suggestion about how I can improve this and make it nicer?

Comment: "that I find it very hard to trust this function"?  What does this mean?  You wrote it.  You tested it.  What possible "trust" concern do you have? Please be very specific on what you don't "trust" about this function.  We can't guess what bothers you. If you want a detailed code review, post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about that, the problem is that now I think it works, but I also thought it worked fine the last 10 times, before I found a possible bug which then I added to the unit tests... I was looking for a possibly smarter way to do something similar to what I'm doing now.

Comment: "I was looking for a possibly smarter way to do something similar to what I'm doing now"?  What?  Please be more specific.  It's not clear what problem you're having with this.  It's also not clear what problem you're trying to solve.  It's not clear to us why your test cases didn't reflect the problem you're actually trying to solve and why your test cases still don't match the problem you're trying to solve.  Do you need help writing the test cases?  Is that the real question?

Comment: It was more "can you see what's wrong with this approach because I know it's wrong but I can't find why"... Then luckily I found it out and I rewrote everything as I wrote below.

Comment: What's wrong?  Please be specific.

Comment: I already explained below what was wrong with that code, I was in short cutting possible paths that would have been perfectly valid if I analyzed the whole path.

Comment: "cutting possible paths that would have been perfectly valid if I analyzed the whole path"?  Where does it say that in the question?  I totally missed seeing that in the question.  Can you provide the words you used **in the question** that explain that problem?  It would help others who also have problems with `walk` if you can be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to modify dirs in place in order to avoid recursive traversal of the removed directories. Use:

```
dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if pred_dir(path.join(base, d))]
```

this will remove the need to check `_ignore_dirs_predicate(base)` (and remove the `NameError` caused by the use of `_ignore_dirs_predicate` instead of `pred_dir`)

You should also rewrite `ISA_PY` to use `str.endswith()`

Comment: Thanks a lot that's what I wanted to hear :) Anyway there is no NameError, just some code which I didn't paste. And about str.endswith() you're right, I used "==" because I was told is much faster.

Comment: "I was told is much faster".  Please discount **everything** you're told is faster.  Please measure.

Comment: I'm not advising endswith because of speed, but because of maintainability

Comment: @andrea If you really notice the difference between `==` and `endsWith` on a program that has to read data from a HARDDISK I'd be more than surprised. Think about it this way: The latency for starting to read on your usual HDD is about 10ms - the difference between comparing two short strings can be measured in a handful cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. What's wrong with the original interface? Apply your predicates to the raw output to get the best results. Beyond an `os.path.join(base, name`), there's not much room to improve.

Comment: He already is applying his predicates to the raw output, no?

Comment: Well in this way I can construct complex boolean predicates and pass them in, and they will be applied by fwalk, I don't think I can do something similar with the original interface..

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [path Python module](http://zoomquiet.org/res/scrapbook/ZqFLOSS/data/20050331112252/).

The original link seems dead: http://jorendorff.com/articles/python/path/

Answer (score 0):

Ok actually I realized that I was doing it all wrong (as I suspected).
The problem is that most of the time I don't know if I want to drop a path or not until I have the complete path.

So for example, given:

```
r1:
    -d1
        + test: file1, file2
r2:
    - d2
```

I can only know when I have the full path "r1/d1/test/file1" what I want to do with that file, so trying to filter before it makes life a lot more complicated.

This is how it becomes now

```
def walk_setup_py(src):
    """Iterate through the setup.py files
    """
    return walk_full_path_files(src, pred_file=ISA_SETUP_PY)


# TODO: this should be the default behaviour
def walk_full_path_files(src, pred_dir=_default_dir_predicate,
                         pred_file=_default_file_predicate):
    """Iterates on the full path given a walker function
    """
    for root, _, files in walk(src):
        for f in files:
            fpath = path.join(root, f)
            if pred_dir(root) and pred_file(f):
                yield fpath
```

Which is way nicer than what I was doing before..